# Access the value from list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

This is one of my class

```
class number11 {
    String ab;
    int i;
    public number11(String ab,int i) {
        this.ab=ab;
        this.i=i;
    }
}
```

And in main method, I used

```
List<number11> n1= new ArrayList<number11>();
```

How can I access the value of integers and String contained in List? I do wish just to print them but to use further.

{Closed ,Thank you all}

Comment: please explain your need clearly.  "How can I access the value of integers and String contained in List?" do you want to access ab and i data from the List?

Comment: Please explain, how to create an object of number11. And Please use upper case for classname.

Comment: Several problems...one [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and `ArrayList` should be [parameterized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Same with `ArrayList`. Second, `String`s and `int`s cannot coexist in the same list. Other than that, you need to use the `List.get` method to access items.

Comment: have look into code conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the list:

```
for (number11 n : list) {
    String ab = n.ab;
    int i = n.i;
    //print ab and i
}
```

Note that `number11` should be in CamelCase to follow Java's conventions: `Number11`.

Comment: better create getters and use them to access `ab` or `i`

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
 List<number11> n1= new ArrayList<number11>();
 for(number11  n:n1){
      System.out.println("String value: "+n.ab);
      System.out.println("int value: "+n.i);

 }
```

According to better coding standards.Follow the below rules
1.Change you class so that It starts with a camel case.
2.Change variables to private.
3.Add setter and getter methods

Comment: have look into code conventions oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you want list of your objects,

- Before continuing, please create getters and setters, I've used them
- Also your class name should be camelCase. `Number11` is valid but not `number11`

You can fill the list using

```
List<number11> list = new ArrayList<number11>();
list.add(new number11("a",1));
list.add(new number11("b",2));
```

To access the members,

```
for (number11 n : list) {
    String ab = n.getAb();
    int i = n.getI();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added values to the ArrayList you can read values by using code such as `n1.get(0).ab` or `n1.get(0).i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List l = new ArrayList<number11>();
    l.add(new number11("x",1));
    l.add(new number11("y",2));
    for (number11 element : l) {
        System.out.println(element.ab + " "+ element.i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might first want to add getter methods to your class number11.

e.g

```
public class number11{
    String ab;
    int i;
    public number11(String ab,int i)
    {
        this.ab=ab;
        this.i=i;
    }

    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }

    public String getAb(){
        return ab;
    }
}
```

You need to obtain a reference to the particular object held inside the ArrayList via the get(index) method where index is the element number starting with 0. Simply call the getter methods to retrieve the values.

e.g

```
List<number11> n1= new ArrayList<number11>();

//Adding the object
n1.add(new number11("Test", 4));

//Retrieving the object.
number11 inst = n1.get(0);

//Retrieve and print the values
System.out.println(inst.getAb());
System.out.println(inst.getI());
```

Answer (score 0):

For better convention change your class structure to,

```
class Number11 {
    private String ab;
    private int i;
    public Number11(String ab,int i) {
        this.ab=ab;
        this.i=i;
    }

    public String getAb() {
        return ab;
    }
    public void setAb(String ab) {
        this.ab = ab;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

}
```

Access in this way.

```
List<number11> n1= new ArrayList<number11>();
if(n1!=null && n1.size()>0){
  for (Number11 n : n1) {
      String ab = n.getAb();
      int i = n.getI();
      //print ab and i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<number11> n1= new ArrayList<number11>();
```

after adding values to this `list` `n1` it will contains `number11` type objects from index `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is number of element you added to list. 
Then you can call what ever object as follows

```
n1.get(1) // this will return 2nd object in the list
```

It will contain `ab` and `i` 
You can call them as follows

```
n1.get(1).getab // 2nd element ab value in list n1
n1.get(1).i // 2nd element i value in list n1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`List` Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) allows to:

Positional access — manipulates elements based on their numerical position in the list

```
MyClass obj = myList.get(24); //--get 25th item of a List<MyClass>--
```

Iteration access — extends Iterator semantics to take advantage of the list's sequential nature

```
for(MyClass obj : myList){ //-- go through all items of a List<MyClass> one by one--
  int i = obj.someField;
}
```

Once you have your object, you can access its fields.